# What does this jQuery selector select?

Tags: jquery

```
$('link[@rel*=style][title]')
```

I know in the first `[]`, it selects elements with attribute `rel` that has content of `'style'`, but I do not know what the second `[]` selects. Anyone can help?

Comment: Not directly related to your question about the second selector, but it's probably worth mentioning that the @ syntax doesn't work with any jQuery version newer than 1.3, and that style needs quotes. $('link[rel*="style"][title]') :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[title]` selector matches elements that have a `title` attribute.

This works fine because, much like IDs or classes, attribute selectors can be chained together to select elements that meet a bunch of criteria at the same time.  With `link[@rel*=style][title]`, you're selecting `<link>` elements that have a `rel` attribute containing "style", *and* have a title attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('link[@rel*=style][title="yourtitle"]');
    $('link[@rel*=style][title*="yourtitle"]');
```

if you write

```
$('link[@rel*=style][title]');
```

then it will select which have title attribute

then it will work

reference **[attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**

Comment: It will work as given in question i.e. without value.. That means that matches elements that have title attribute... as said by @cHao